# Github Fork & Pull: My PR was accepted, how to keep working on my fork?

Tags: git, github

Recently I started collaborating to an open source project.

Using the fork and pull method I sent my first PR and it has been approved.

How can I work on the next issue using the same forked repository?

Since my PR has been merged my current master branch is behind the original repository.

I managed to think about two solutions:

1. merge the PR branch to my master branch and create a new branch based on master to work on the new issue.
2. create an "upstream" remote and execute a pull on local master branch.

Which one is better? Is there another option?

Comment: You will need to keep your fork up-to-date with upstream anyway, so pulling upstream master is the right choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't work on `master` in your local repository.  A good workflow looks like this:

- Fork the upstream repository on github.
- Clone the upstream repository locally:

  ```
  git clone git@github.com:/someproject/somerepo.git
  ```
- Add your fork as an additional remote:

  ```
  cd somerepo
  git remote add mine git@github.com:/me/somerepo.git
  ```
- Make sure your local repository is up-to-date with respect to the upstream repository.  Obviously this is already the case if you just cloned it, but otherwise:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git pull
  ```

  Note that this will pull from the upstream `master` branch, not your fork.  This is what you want.
- Create a new branch off master for your work:

  ```
  git checkout -b my-spiffy-feature
  ```
- Do you work, and push the branch to your fork:

  ```
  git push -u mine my-spiffy-feature
  ```
- Submit a pull request against the upstream master.

At this point, you can start doing other work.  You can create another new branch off master:

```
    git checkout -b another-feature master
```

Or you can base it on your previous work, if necessary:

```
    git checkout -b another-feature my-spiffy-feature
```

When your previous pull request is accepted upstream, update your local master branch:

```
    git checkout master
    git pull
```

And then rebase any existing work off the updated master branch:

```
    git checkout another-feature
    git rebase master
```

With this workflow, `master` always tracks upstream, and your work is always done on isolated branches, which makes it easy to handle multiple pull requests.

Comment: I did not work on master branch. Your solution looks good, can I just change the remotes of my current cloned repo?

Comment: Yeah sure.  `git remote add` for adding new remotes; `git remote set-url` for changing the url of an existing remote, etc.